# How to add rows to a table based on widget inputs?

Tags: r, shiny

I´m trying to add rows to a dataframe based on the widget selection when a button is clicked.

I´ve put the `observeEvent` inside the `renderTable`, but the app returns an error: *cannot coerce class "c("Observer", "R6")" to a data.frame*.

This is the test dataframe to add rows to:

```r
> DF <- data.frame(matrix(c("A","B"), ncol = 2), stringsAsFactors = FALSE)
> colnames(DF) <- c("col1", "col2")
> DF
  col1 col2
1    A    B
```

And this is the shiny app code:

```r
library(shiny)

DF <- data.frame(matrix(c("A","B"), ncol = 2), stringsAsFactors = FALSE)
colnames(DF) <- c("col1", "col2")

ui <- fluidPage(

  titlePanel("Save input"),

  sidebarLayout(
    sidebarPanel(

      wellPanel(
        h3("Widget 1"),
        radioButtons("add", "Letter", c("A", "B", "C"))
      ),

      wellPanel(
        h3("Save button"),
        actionButton("save", "Save")       
      )
    ),

    mainPanel(
      tableOutput("table")
    )
  )
)

server <- function(input, output) {

  output$table <- renderTable({
    DF

    observeEvent(input$save, {
      l <- nrow(DF)
      DF[l+1,] <- list(input$add, input$add)
    })

  })

}

shinyApp(ui = ui, server = server)
```

[App](https://i.stack.imgur.com/cpGAE.png)

Do you know what is wrong?

**UPDATE:**

With @Rémi answer the error is gone but the app does not add new rows to the table: [app](https://i.stack.imgur.com/zLJCR.png)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you just want to display your table you should put the DF after observeEvent because "observeEvent returns an observer reference class object" so when you have a `renderTable` you must return a matrix or a data.frame.

```
server <- function(input, output) {
  output$table <- renderTable({
    observeEvent(input$save, {
      l <- nrow(DF)
      DF[l+1,] <- list(input$add, input$add)
    })
    DF
  })
}
```

Edit 1 :
If I well understand your request, you don't need to save the data frame but you want to add row, it could be the same, you just need to use `rbind` as sugest the following post :

[Add row to shinyTable](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37448344/add-row-to-shinytable)

Comment: hey @Rémi, that solves the error but the app doesn´t add a new row to the table when you click the button, please see the screenshot in the update in the OP.